# I'd like to put YAML data in a GitHub Pages jekyll theme

Tags: yaml, jekyll, github-pages, liquid

I am running a series of [websites with information about the COVID-19 pandemic](https://covid-at-home.info) in different languages. They live in their own GitHub repositories and are served using GitHub Pages. Right now each of these repositories has a copy of all the files except the ones that are part of the [theme](https://github.com/pages-themes/slate). Somewhat inconveniently, I have no previous experience with Jekyll, Ruby or GitHub Pages.

I know there are multilingual jekyll tricks, but that is not what I am here for, mostly because I want sites on different domains.

So I decided that it might be good to hijack the theme as a store for files common to my sites. So I made a [test copy](https://github.com/covid-at-home/testsite) of my site without the common files. It uses as "`remote_theme`" a [copy](https://github.com/covid-at-home/common) of the theme where I stuck my common files in the theme's assets directory, so they get pulled in by the different language sites. This works for images, PDF files and such: I just move them to `/assets/images` in the theme and it all works.

However, next to data files local to each language, such as the menu below our site title, I also have some common data files, such as the list of languages that the site is available in and the list of volunteers we thank for their work. I'd like to also place these in the theme somehow so I don't have to commit them to all the repos separately... Cannot get this to work.

What I have tried:

- Adding `_data` to the regexp in the `.gemspec` file of the theme where it reads:
  `f.match(%r{^((_includes|_layouts|_sass|assets)/|(LICENSE|README)((\.(txt|md|markdown)|$)))}i)`

  > Does not lead to the data files being accessible
- Creating dummy _data files that `{% include` the real ones from the theme's `_include` dir.

  > "`found character that cannot start any token while scanning for the next token`"
- Set `data_dir` in `_config.yml` to `assets/data`

  > I can use the data files that are site specific just fine, but the data files on the theme side are not seen by the Liquid processing. (They are copied to the `_site` directory along with the site-specific ones.)

Is there a way to have a GitHub Pages site with some data coming from its own files and some data coming from the theme files? I realise I'd probably have to rebuild the site to make the theme changes show. (Right?) (Is there a way to trigger a rebuild on GitHub Pages other than to change files? What does the version number on the theme do?)

Is there a more in-depth writeup of how the files from the theme and the site get mixed and what order things happen in than the jekyll user documentation?

Please by all means also tell me if there's a much better, simpler and/or more elegant way to do what I am trying to accomplish. We have a fast-growing existing project, but I'm ready to do things differently if that's simply better...

Comment: You can use @ashmaroli plugin and your own theme on platforms like https://netlify.com. You even can trigger builds across repositories with [build hooks](https://docs.netlify.com/configure-builds/build-hooks/).

Comment: Thanks @DavidJacquel. Was hoping to use only GitHub Pages, but will have a look at netlify.

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin I have authored to have Jekyll load data files from a theme:
https://github.com/ashmaroli/jekyll-data

But it won't be used by GitHub Pages directly. So you'll have to build locally or elsewhere and push the contents of `_site` directory to GitHub

Comment: Thanks...! But I guess the fact that you wrote a plugin for it means that it probably can't be done in some sneaky way that I just hadn't thought of... H,,,, I was hoping to do this all using just Github, and I have zero experience with Ruby, Gems, jekyll or any of this stuff. And it would mean I have to push the resulting sites to GitHub, which kinda defeats the purpose, because then I might as well just push the data files to multiple places. Hmmmmmmmmm...